# Interaction Technique for Augmented Reality

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, scatter

I visualized a scatter plot in AR with Vuforia.

User can see the Scatter Plot with ARTag but I do not know how to make interaction. What would be the best technique for the user to select multiple points. I would like to make for the user to select the different points close to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a raycast to select these multiple points.